# Two types of kohanim; are there any practical differences between them?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, kohen-priest, pinchas-the-man

[Peninim on the Torah](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/peninim/) says:

Thus, the Kehunah, which he (Pinchas) received as a reward, was a totally new Kehunah, not connected with that of Aharon HaKohen.

Are there any practical differences between the two types of kohanim; those directly descended from Aharon and those descended from Pinchas? 
Differences could be halachic or in their character.

Answer (score 3):

[Rashi on Zevachim 101b](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Zevachim.101b.13.1?lang=bi) (in some texts) understands the gemara to derive a principle that after Pinchas' act of peacemaking between the tribes, only descendants of Pinchas would be appointed as High Priests.

(Historically, this seems to have been the case (at least after the the High Priesthood was removed from the House of Eli in the days of David) as noted by [Tosafot](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Zevachim.101b.13?lang=bi) ad loc.)

Comment: I don't think he's saying that other kohanim would be invalid as kohein gadol, just he got a blessing to have them

Comment: I think your reading is correct. I've softened the language a little to reflect that

Comment: Then this isn't really a qualitative difference in the type of kehuna they have, I'd think

Comment: The OP asked for "practical" differences between the two sets of kohanim. One practical difference is whether (in practice) a kohen would have a chance of being appointed kohen gadol. Whether that stems from a "qualitative difference in the type of kehuna they have" is not currently something I currently feel qualified to opine on either way.